# type as method parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I am using Python 3.7, developing using PyCharm.

My intention is for a simple method that takes a type, for example type(str), type(int) and so on. I can't seem to get this to work.

What I want to be able to do is pass in the type and then test against it within a method.

Let me show you have I have:

```
def TypeTestMethod(self, t):
    print(f't is {t} | Type of t: {type(t)}')

    if(t == type(str)):
        print(f'Type is str')

    if(t == type(int)):
        print('Type is int')
```

When I call it, I pass in a type. An example of a call would be as follows:

```
TypeTestMethod(t=type(str))
```

My hope would be that this type(str) would be passed in and then hit that first if statement, but not the second. At the moment this is not happening; it hits both statements and prints out both 'Type is str' *and* 'Type is int'.

If you're curious about the first print statement, it prints the following:

```
t is <class 'type'> | Type of t: <class 'type'>
```

So for whatever reason, the data is not working correctly in the method.

There are two solutions I can see, but neither of them seem at all elegant. The first is to supply an example variable of the type I want. I'd rather not declare more memory than I need if necessary, so if it comes to a 'datetime' example, that might be troublesome. The other is to create my own enum and do it that way. This is of course possible for the task at hand, but it seems clunky. The types are already in the system - surely I can just use the existing ones instead.

Surely there's a way.

Comment: You should use `type` inversely. `if type(t) == str:`. But it is not recommended to compare type this way. `if isinstance(t, str):` is more useful, because it can handle subtypes.

Comment: `type(str)` is not a `str`, it's a `type`

Comment: If you are really passing the *type* `str` as the argument, you would use something like `t is str` rather than `t == type(str)`, or preferably `issubclass(t, str)` (the analog of `isinstance(t, str)` if `t` were really a `str` value.

Comment: I might misunderstand your question. If `t` is a type, you should compare like `if t == str:` or `issubtype(t, str)`. And call it `TypeTestMethod(t=str)`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using this function?

Comment: We have an [obvious XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.  Please edit your question to explain the __real__ problem you're trying to solve instead of what you think is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a combination of our comments, I *think* what you want is

```
def type_test_function(self, t):
    print(f't is {t} | Type of t: {type(t)}')

    if issubclass(t, str):  # Or t is str, if you don't want to catch subclasses
        print(f'Type is str')

    if issubclass(t, int):
        print('Type is int')
```

`type(str)` gives you the type of the `str` type, that is, `type` itself. Your argument should either be `type("some string")` or simply `str`.

```
type_test_function(str)
type_test_function(int)
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having multiple functions, you could use 
[functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)

You define a generic function, and then register specialised functions for different types (dispatched on the first argument).  The generic function is called is no specialist function matches the argument.

```
@singledispatch
def test_method_type(arg):
    print('Generic output')

@test_method_type.register(int)
def _(arg):
    print('Integer argument')

@test_method_type.register(str)
def _(arg):
    print('String argument')

test_method_type(42)
Integer argument

test_method_type('hello')
String argument

test_method_type(b'hello')
Generic output
```

If you use type annotations, the dispatch type will be inferred from the first function argument

```
@test_method_type.register
def _(arg: list):
    print('List argument')
```

In Python3.8, there is also the [functools.singledispatchmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod) decorator for methods.

```
from functools import singledispatchmethod


class Typer:

    @singledispatchmethod
    def test_method_type(self, arg):
        print('Generic output')

    @test_method_type.register(bool)
    def _(self, arg):
        print('Boolean argument')

    @test_method_type.register(int)
    def _(self, arg):
        print('Integer argument')

    @test_method_type.register(str)
    def _(self, arg):
        print('String argument')


typer = Typer()

typer.test_method_type(False)
Boolean argument

typer.test_method_type(42)
Integer argument

typer.test_method_type('hello')
String argument

typer.test_method_type(None)
Generic output
```

Answer (score 0):

`type` is actually a class, and it's [the metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) for `object` - which is itself the base class for all classes (in Py3 at least).  So when you call your function with

```
TypeTestMethod(t=type(str))
```

What you are passing as value is already the `type` class, hence the result you get. Then in your function:

```
if(t == type(str)):
    print(f'Type is str')
```

Here again, you are comparing `t` against `type(str)`, which is still the `type` class.

Your question doesn't clearly states what you're really trying to do here, but you obviously don't really understand Python's type system, so I suggest you [read the 
doc about Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and test things in your Python shell (that's what it's for mainly) to double-check your understanding. A couple builtin functions that might also interest you are `isinstance(obj, cls)` and `issubclass(cls, othercls)`.